# Oracle SQL - reducing the number of selected attributes changes the result

Tags: sql, oracle

I was just playing around with joins and found this weird problem:

I tried something like this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM ((EMPLOYEES INNER JOIN DEPARTMENTS USING(DEPARTMENT_ID))
  NATURAL JOIN LOCATIONS);
```

The result was 106 rows. Then, I only wanted to select those rows where the CITY attribute is equal to 'Toronto', so I did this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM ((EMPLOYEES INNER JOIN DEPARTMENTS USING(DEPARTMENT_ID))
  NATURAL JOIN LOCATIONS)
  WHERE CITY = 'Toronto';
```

the result contained exactly the 2 rows with CITY equal to 'Toronto' that I needed. However, I did not need all the columns, so I changed the query to

```
SELECT LAST_NAME, JOB_ID, DEPARTMENT_ID, DEPARTMENT_NAME, CITY
  FROM ((EMPLOYEES INNER JOIN DEPARTMENTS USING(DEPARTMENT_ID))
  NATURAL JOIN LOCATIONS)
  WHERE CITY = 'Toronto';
```

This gives me 106 rows and CITY is always set to 'Toronto', which doesn't make any sense to me. Another weird thing is that when I select the attribute LOCATION_ID as well, the result is correct(2 rows I wanted).

Here are the relevant relation schemata:

```
describe EMPLOYEES
Name           Null     Type         
-------------- -------- ------------ 
EMPLOYEE_ID    NOT NULL NUMBER(6)    
FIRST_NAME              VARCHAR2(20)    
LAST_NAME      NOT NULL VARCHAR2(25)  
JOB_ID         NOT NULL VARCHAR2(10)
DEPARTMENT_ID           NUMBER(4) 

describe DEPARTMENTS
Name            Null     Type         
--------------- -------- ------------ 
DEPARTMENT_ID   NOT NULL NUMBER(4)    
DEPARTMENT_NAME NOT NULL VARCHAR2(30) 
MANAGER_ID               NUMBER(6)    
LOCATION_ID              NUMBER(4)  

describe locations
Name           Null     Type         
-------------- -------- ------------ 
LOCATION_ID    NOT NULL NUMBER(4)    
CITY           NOT NULL VARCHAR2(30)
```

I know can I write this query in 50 different and simpler ways, but I want to know what went wrong with this. I use Oracle SQL Developer.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't know what goes wrong but don't use natural joins. Instead explicitly define the joins. Natural joins do things automagically for you. Not a good thing when programming.

```
SELECT LAST_NAME, JOB_ID, DEPARTMENT_ID, DEPARTMENT_NAME, CITY
FROM EMPLOYEES INNER JOIN DEPARTMENTS USING(DEPARTMENT_ID)
JOIN LOCATIONS ON (locations.location_id = departments.location_id)
WHERE CITY = 'Toronto';

Hartstein   MK_MAN  20  Marketing   Toronto
Fay         MK_REP  20  Marketing   Toronto
```

And lose the Parentheses, they are confusing and serve no purpose here.

EDIT:
explain plan shows there is a cartesian product on Location. So natural join can not find a join condition and does a cartasian product. 
Once more : natural joins are evil ;-)
See : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Natural_join

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                     | Name        | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT              |             |   106 |  4770 |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  MERGE JOIN CARTESIAN         |             |   106 |  4770 |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   MERGE JOIN                  |             |   106 |  3816 |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| DEPARTMENTS |    27 |   432 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |     INDEX FULL SCAN           | DEPT_ID_PK  |    27 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  5 |    SORT JOIN                  |             |   107 |  2140 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   6 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL         | EMPLOYEES   |   107 |  2140 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   7 |   BUFFER SORT                 |             |     1 |     9 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  8 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN           | LOC_CITY_IX |     1 |     9 |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Don't use `NATURAL JOIN` - it's just asking for trouble (consider the case when someone renames a column in one of the tables).

Long answer:

There are a couple of reasons why these queries might return different results:

- one of them might use Query Rewrite (if an eligible materialized view exists); check the `EXPLAIN PLAN` for both queries
- you might encounter an Oracle bug; you didn't mention the version / patchlevel you're running, so it's difficult to tell, see below for a short list of possible candidates

[Wikipedia article about NATURAL JOIN mentioning they're dangerous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Natural_join)

[WRONG RESULTS bug, referencing Metalink #406966.1](http://www.freelists.org/post/oracle-l/WRONG-RESULTS-bug-in-92x-101x-and-102x)

[Oracle forum discussion on buggy NATURAL JOINs](https://community.oracle.com/thread/651878?start=0&tstart=0)